# how to build custom Edit Text editing with selective splitter?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a custom text editor to specify in XML with which splitter the three-digit digits can be separated by three digits.
After a general search, I could not find the right and definite answer.
what can i do?
Thanks in advance.

Custom edit text class:

```
package com.example.customamount;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
public class CustomAmount extends CustomEditText {
    String customSplitter;
    public CustomAmount(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomAmount(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomSplitor(context,attrs);
    }

    public CustomAmount(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setCustomSplitor(context,attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomSplitor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray b = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomAmount);
        customSplitter=b.getString(R.styleable.CustomAmount_cutSplitter);
        setCustomSplitter();
                b.recycle();


    }

    private void setCustomSplitter() {
        this.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcherForThousand(this,customSplitter));
    }
}
```

TextWatcher Class:

```
package com.example.customamount;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public  class NumberTextWatcherForThousand implements TextWatcher {
     EditText editText;
     String customSplitor;

    public NumberTextWatcherForThousand(EditText editText, String customSplitor) {
        this.editText = editText;
        this.customSplitor = customSplitor;
    }

    public NumberTextWatcherForThousand(CustomAmount customAmount, String customSplitter) {
    }

     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

     }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         try {
             editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
             String value = editText.getText().toString();


             if (value != null && !value.equals("")) {

                 if (value.startsWith(".")) {
                     editText.setText("0.");
                 }
                 if (value.startsWith("0") && !value.startsWith("0.")) {
                     editText.setText("");

                 }


                 String str = editText.getText().toString().replaceAll(this.customSplitor, "");
                 if (!value.equals("")) {
                     editText.setText(getDecimalFormattedString(str,customSplitor));
                 }
                 editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
             }
             editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
             return;
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
             editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
         }

     }

    public static String getDecimalFormattedString(String value, String per) {
        StringTokenizer lst = new StringTokenizer(value, ".");
        String str1 = value;
        String str2 = "";
        if (lst.countTokens() > 1) {
            str1 = lst.nextToken();
            str2 = lst.nextToken();
        }
        String str3 = "";
        int i = 0;
        int j = -1 + str1.length();
        if (str1.charAt(-1 + str1.length()) == '.') {
            j--;
            str3 = ".";
        }
        for (int k = j; ; k--) {
            if (k < 0) {
                if (str2.length() > 0)
                    str3 = str3 + "." + str2;
                return str3;
            }
            if (i == 3) {
                str3 = per + str3;
                i = 0;
            }
            str3 = str1.charAt(k) + str3;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.example.customamount.CustomEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:cutFont="@string/baseFont"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
        <com.example.customamount.CustomAmount
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/textt"
            app:cutSplitter="/"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

error on run:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.customamount, PID: 28664
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.customamount.NumberTextWatcherForThousand.afterTextChanged(NumberTextWatcherForThousand.java:59)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9795)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:12547)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1273)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:576)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:506)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:36)
        at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:131)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:7690)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:7467)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2720)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:12463)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:432)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1820)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3426)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:115)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:133)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2814)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:346)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5199)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5067)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4605)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4613)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4802)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4605)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4613)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7283)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7244)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4356)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

custom Edit Text class:

```
package com.example.customamount;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText;

public class CustomEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
    String customFont;
    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText);
        customFont=a.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_cutFont);
        setCustomFont(context, customFont);
        a.recycle();

    }
    public void setCustomFont(Context context, String asset) {
        if (asset == null || asset.isEmpty()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.baseFont));
            setTypeface(tf);
        } else {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), asset);
            setTypeface(tf);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `this` in your `new NumberTextWatcherForThousand(this,customSplitter)` inside `class CustomAmount` refer to

```
public NumberTextWatcherForThousand(CustomAmount customAmount, String customSplitter) {
}
```

and you haven't set your EditText inside this constructor, so your EditText got null. Edit your constructor to be like this:

```
public NumberTextWatcherForThousand(CustomAmount customAmount String customSplitter) {
    this.editText = customAmount;
    this.customSplitor = customSplitter;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i just change my constructor like you siad and it working